# how to keep a div visible after jquery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to implement a jQuery .animate call to toggle the height of several div's. One of the div's I would like to disappear as it currently does, but the other div I would like to remain visible. How can I accomplish this? Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#divTitle').on('click', function() {
    $('#divDetails').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#divContents').animate({marginTop:'toggle',display:'block'},'slow');
  })
});
```

...

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Could you post your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: wait...selecting an id should slide and animate only one element ( the one with the selected ID ), maybe you shold post us some code for a better understanding :)

Comment: To see a demo, go to http://staging.cliquesoft.org/test/ and click the "Whatever Title" bar.

Comment: I found a resolution from the jQuery IRC:
    marginTop: parseInt($('#divContents').css('marginTop').replace("px","")) > 0 ? 0: 317

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.animate()` put another div between yours that will be instead of margin property:

```
<div id="divMargin" style="height: 10px;"></div>
```

Then `.slideToggle()` it in your function:

```
$('#divTitle').on('click', function() {
  $('#divDetails').slideToggle('slow');
  $('#divMargin').slideToggle('slow');
})
```

Comment: Thanks Wilq for the suggestion, but it looks like that just prevents the divContents animation from taking place.

Comment: Ok, I've found other way, try it now.